# xpath: how to get the specific text using xpath?

Tags: xpath

the html is like this:

```
<div id='id'>
    <a href>abc</a>
"xyz"
</div>
```

I want to use xpath to get the xyz (I use it in capybara), but my xpath can't work

... //div[@id='id'].text

it returns abcxyz

how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is its own text node, so the correct selector would be:

```
.//div[@id='id']/text()
```

Comment: Sorry, this xpath works for xpath, but not work for capybara. do you know how to write it in capybara?   find(:xpath, "//div[@class='publisherStatus']/text()")

Comment: the error is : The given selector //div[@class='publisherStatus']/text() is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: Sorry don't know much about cabybara, but `(Capybara::Element) find(*args)` suggests, that you can only select elements, so the text node you are looking for might be a node in XSLT, but unfortunately not an `Capybara::Element`.